# How can i find the sum?

Tags: summation

How can i calculate this serias?
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^m}{2^i}\cdot i$$
I tried to do:
$$\ 2^m\cdot\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+...+\frac{n}{2^n}\right]$$
And i don't know how to continue..
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf#) to know methods to solve this summation easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$s(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+...+\frac{n}{2^n}\quad (1)$$

multiply by $1/2$ and get

$$\frac{s(n)}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{2}{2^3}+...+\frac{n-1}{2^{n}}+\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\quad (2)$$

Now make $(1)-(2)$ and get

$$\frac{s(n)}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n}}-\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\\
s(n)=\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]-\frac{n}{2^{n}}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you!!

Comment: @Mathing: you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{d}{da}a^{-i} = -ia^{-i-1}\implies -a\frac{d}{da}a^{-i} = ia^{-i}
$$
we can write your sum as
$$
a^m\sum_{i=1}^n -a\frac{d}{da}a^{-i} = -a^{m+1}\frac{d}{da}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(a^{-1}\right)^i
$$
Can you take it from here and replace $a$ with $2$?